# Mark on the forehead in Ezekiel 9:4

Tags: ezekiel

In Ezekiel 9:4, the man clothed in linen is ordered to go through the city putting a protective mark on the foreheads of the faithful.

When I asked what the mark was, my professor said that it was a tau. When I asked why a tau, he shrugged and said that it was the last letter of the Hebrew alphabet and looked like a table.

What was the mark really?  Someone else said that in the original the mark could have been a plus or an x.  I hate confusion.  What was the mark and why that character?

Comment: Related: "[Who is the man in linen in Ezekiel 9?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/9291/)"

Answer (score 8):

I wonder about OP's teacher... Be that as it may, the explanation is fairly simple. Here's the [Hebrew and English for Ezekiel 9:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%209%3A1-4&version=ESV;WLC)

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהוָה֙ [אלו] אֵלָ֔יו* עֲבֹר֙ בְּת֣וֹךְ הָעִ֔יר בְּת֖וֹךְ יְרֽוּשָׁלִָ֑ם **וְהִתְוִ֨יתָ תָּ֜ו** עַל־מִצְח֣וֹת הָאֲנָשִׁ֗ים הַנֶּֽאֱנָחִים֙ וְהַנֶּ֣אֱנָקִ֔ים עַ֚ל כָּל־הַתּ֣וֹעֵב֔וֹת הַֽנַּעֲשׂ֖וֹת בְּתוֹכָֽהּ׃
>
> *wayyōmɛr YHWH ʾēlå̄w ʿăḇōr bəṯōḵ hå̄ʿīr bəṯōḵ yərūšå̄lå̄yim **wəhiṯwīṯå̄ tå̄w** ʿal-miṣḥōṯ hå̄ʾănå̄šīm hannɛʾɛ̆nå̄ḥīm wəhannɛʾɛ̆nå̄qīm ʿal kål-hattōʿēḇōṯ hannaʿăśōṯ bəṯōḵå̄h*
>
> The Lord said to him, “Go through the midst of the city, even through the midst of Jerusalem, **and put a mark** on the foreheads of the men who sigh and groan over all the abominations which are being committed in its midst.” <sub>NASB</sub>

I've put the key bit in bold: it says (fairly) **literally** "put a *taw* on the foreheads...".`†`

So that's why the teacher said it was a [`ת` = *taw* = last letter of the Hebrew *alephbet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taw) -- because that's the instruction that's given in Ezekiel 9:4!

But why an "X" or a "+"? Because that's the letter-shape of the letter *taw* in Ezekiel's time, in the so-called ["paleo Hebrew" alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleo-Hebrew_alphabet). You can see the shape well in this "letter" (ostracon) from [Lachish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lachish_letters) (this is [#2](http://www.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=364095&partId=1)):

[image: Lachish Letter 6]

The letter *taw* has been circled in red (I don't think I've missed any).

So in answer to OP's question:

> What was the mark and why that character?

The mark really was a paleo-Hebrew *taw*, because that's what the LORD instructed the the "man clothed in linen" to do.

---

<sub>`†` As was [pointed out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35351422#35351422) to me, a properly literal translation would be something like: "Go through the midst of the city, even through the midst of Jerusalem, **and *taw* a *taw*** on the foreheads...", since the verb here, for "put a mark" is `I` תָּוָה, see [BDB, p. 1063a](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/1063/mode/1up) for more.</sub>

Comment: Also, the introduction to Gesenius's grammar provides a [facsimile of the Siloam Inscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJMMu.png), which provides another excellent example of paleo-Hebrew.

Comment: + The Wikipedia entry for the [Siloam inscription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siloam_inscription) includes photographs of the original, which makes a good reference for the line drawing Joseph provided. It's helpful to have the comparison; the advantage of the Lachish example is that it is pen (stylus) and ink (i.e., more like Ezekiel 9), rather than lapidary incision.

Comment: Interesting.  To some of my fellow students, the mark looks like a cross, but the prof said it couldn't be since they didn't know about crosses back in Ezekiel's day.  A cross would be interesting, but he is probably right.

Comment: @TedDeRose See p. 391 in [this account of Wilhelm Vischer](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PepGAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA7&pg=PA388#v=onepage&q&f=false) for one interpreter who found in the paleo-Hebrew *tav* an anticipation of the mark of the cross, in his linking of Genesis 4 + Ezekiel 9 + Revelation 7.

Comment: Bless you.  The reference and access to such material unfamiliar to me is why I joined and post.

Comment: Perhaps phrase "x marks the spot" is more timeless than I realized.